# Inserting labels into image alt tag in Blogger

Tags: blogs, blogger, label

Just wondering whether anyone knows how to get blogger labels into "alt" tags in an image. I have tried `alt="data:post.labels"` to no available at all?

Doesn't anyone know how to assist with this on blogger?

P.S - I know about the ‘rel=tag’ - but for the specific template, I want to have the labels appear as text in the alt tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you may be using the XML version of templating Blogger. If that's the case, then you'll need to use something like the below if you want to have the ALT attribute show up with the name of the tag:

```
expr:alt='data:label.name'
```

You can use the same principle to display the label/tag in the TITLE attribute of a link, link so:

```
<a expr:href='data:label.url' expr:title='data:label.name'><data:label.name/></a>
```